# How can I search users by id

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

Correct me if I'm wrong but it appears that the admin-sdks's Users>[list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) operation doesnt support searching users by ID (According to the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users)).

For example I use the Members api to get all the members of a given group. It returns a list or User Ids. 
The only way to fetch data about those users is to call the [get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) operation for each user. Seems pretty inefficient to me.

How come this functionality is not implemented (or perhaps I'm missing something)?

Answer (score 0):

Search feature means you have a pattern and you want the list of all entities which relate to given pattern. It assumes you don't have the unique id of the entity you need. The output of search feature is the list of unique ids with optional additional minimal information which matches to search pattern. To get full information of the individual entity, you need to use unique id and use get information feature.

However, if you already have the unique id, then you don't need the search function. Directly use get information feature.

So google has provided sufficient functionality. If you already have userid, why using search call, use retrieve user call directly.

Comment: Seems pretty wasteful to have to use the `get` call on each user to fetch information when you want to get details for a bunch of users. For example there is no convenient way to get user information of all members of a certain group. Other similar directory apis I worked with provide such functionality.